# undeclared identifier (TBlobStream)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

When I declare a variable like this :

```
Var Stream : TBlobStream;
```

I get an error :

> undeclared identifier

So what is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: @DownVoter Can you tell me please why the downvote? at least leave a comment , is my question not clear or what?

Comment: In a comment on you earlier q today which you deleted, the reason Delphi cannot find DBTables.Pas is that it is one of the BDE units which is no longer installed by default, you have to do it manually.

Comment: @MartynA But it seems unlikely that Sami is using BDE and so this is not going to be very useful I suspect.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Maybe. I was only commenting on his compilation problem in the deleted q, which was about DBTables not being found.

Comment: You both , I'm not using BDE , and stop downvote my posts for no reason

Comment: @MartynA The entire problem (this Q and the deleted Q) is a mistaken desire to declare a variable of type `TBlobStream`. Use `CreateBlobStream` and stop caring about the implementation details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you tell me why you keep downvote all my questions? for no reason as I see

Comment: @Sami:  I certainly didn't d-vote this or your earlier q.  I was only commenting on this one in case you were still having the DBTables problem.

Comment: @sami Voting is anonymous. You have no more idea than I do who casts votes. My advice is to stop worrying about voting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes , I'm sure that the first time you see this post , you d-vote it , and for explanation , if somone ask a Q that mean he need help , and he don't know how to fix , he does not need a blam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the abstract `TStream` class here. That's just what the [CreateBlobStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.CreateBlobStream) method returns.

Answer (score 2):

You don't declare a variable of that type.

You call, for instance, [`CreateBlobStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.CreateBlobStream) on a dataset and then read or write with that stream.

Note that `CreateBlobStream` has return type of `TStream`. That's the abstract base class for all streams. The actual runtime type will be a concrete derived class, but don't need to know the actual runtime type to use this. In this way you are insulated from the implementation details.

So you would declare a local variable of type `TStream` and assign the value returned by `CreateBlobStream` to that variable. The Fish Facts example demonstrates this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FishFacts_(Delphi)